# KeyboardInterrupt close failed in file object destructor: sys.excepthook is missing lost sys.stderr

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 


import sys, re 




def find_position(line):
    pun = ""
    if re.search(r"[.?!]+", line):
        pun = re.search(r"[.?!]+", line).group()
    pos = line.find(pun)
    pos = pos+len(pun)-1
    return pos




def sentence_splitter(filename):

    f = open(filename, "r")

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        print line + "\n"
        while line:
            pos  =  find_position(line)
            line2 = line[ : pos+1].split(" ")
            length = len(line2)
            last_word = line2[length -1]

        try:
                if re.search(r"[A-Z]+.*", last_word) or  line[pos+1] != " " or line[pos+2].islower() :
                print line[:pos+1],
                line = line[pos+1:]

            else:
            print line[ : pos+1]
                line = line[pos+1 :]


            except :
                print " error here!!"      

    f.close()        
    return " bye bye"





if __name__=="__main__":
    print sentence_splitter(sys.argv[1])
```

---

on executing it

```
python sentence_splitter6.py  README  | more
```

---

error occur

```
KeyboardInterrupt
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

also i have to press clr+c

it is not closed by its own

tried stuffs on this 
[How to handle a file destructor throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177903/how-to-handle-a-file-destructor-throwing-an-exception)

[How to silence "sys.excepthook is missing" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790328/how-to-silence-sys-excepthook-is-missing-error)

links also but not saisfied please help

Comment: Check your indentation in the `sentence_splitter` function. Correct indenting is required in python.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is here:

```
while line:
    pos = find_position(line)
    line2 = line[:pos + 1].split(" ")
    length = len(line2)
    last_word = line2[length - 1]
```

`line` is not modified, so if its true once, it's always true, the `while` have no way to end.

Then, the `KeyboardInterrupt` does not comes from your execution but from you pressing `C-c`, halting your program.

Also you should respect the PEP8 while writing python code, also you can check it with `flakes8` and/or `pylint`.

Here is PEP8 compliant version (still have the infinite loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, re


def find_position(line):
    pun = ""
    if re.search(r"[.?!]+", line):
        pun = re.search(r"[.?!]+", line).group()
    pos = line.find(pun)
    pos = pos+len(pun)-1
    return pos


def sentence_splitter(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line + "\n")
            while line:
                pos = find_position(line)
                line2 = line[:pos + 1].split(" ")
                length = len(line2)
                last_word = line2[length - 1]
            if ((re.search(r"[A-Z]+.*", last_word) or
                 line[pos+1] != " " or
                 line[pos+2].islower())):
                print(line[:pos+1], end='')
                line = line[pos+1:]
            else:
                print(line[:pos + 1])
                line = line[pos + 1:]
        return " bye bye"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sentence_splitter(sys.argv[1]))
```

Finally, you should comment your code so everyone including you can understand what you're doing, like:

```
def find_position(line):
    """Finds the position of a pun in the line.
    """
```

Also `find_pun_position` is probably a better name...